# iPhone 3.1.3 sdk for Leopard

Tags: iphone, sdk, osx-leopard, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

Is it still possible to find the 3.1.3 SDK (w/ Xcode) for iPhone development on Leopard?

I haven't upgraded to Snow Leopard yet, but I need to interact with devices running 3.1.3.  I should have grabbed that version when it was up, but I didn't.

So, does anyone have a link to the 3.1.3 iPhone SDK (w/ Xcode)?

Comment: You should really update to 10.6.3 and use the supported version of Xcode ;)

Comment: I have this thing about not upgrading my entire OS in the middle of a project.  :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, just copied the link I had in my Firefox download history instead of download manager. [How about this](http://adcdownload.apple.com/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1.3__final/iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.1.4__leopard__9m2809a.dmg)?

Note: you'll need to log in first.

Comment: That appears to be the right link!  Very nice.
Did you find it linked somewhere on their web site or just have it cached somewhere?

Comment: It still works, at least for me. Had to retry it twice before it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for 2 weeks cause I had a borrowed mac book and did not have permission to upgrade to snow leopard. I finally [found it on a mac page](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=898518) it has all the SDK's.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it here (requires login): https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ (filter for Xcode 3.1)