# Programming on Leopard for iPhone OS 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, ipod-touch, osx-leopard

I got Leopard with XCode 3.1 and SDK 3.0, when opening the organizer and trying to debug on my ipod I received
"The version of iPhone OS on "..." does not match any of the versions of iPhone OS supported for development with this copy of xCode...".
It tells me with my xCode I can only develop for iPhone OS 3.0 or less, so I downloaded the new xCode + SDK installation bundle, knowing the SDK can't be installed on Leopard.

In the installation it tells me "If you don't want to install the SDK, press disagree", and so I did, but in the next screen he forces me to choose a drive for the SDK, and then says "you can't install the SDK on leopard system", and I can't pass this screen.

My question is: is it even possible to program on Leopard for iPhone OS 3.1.3? I really want to debug my apps on my iPod (framework 3.1.3, 3G)

Thanks ahead!!

Edit: Downloading seperatly xCode without the SDK didn't work, now I just got no SDKs for iPhone OS.
I can't program for 3.1.3 without upgrading to snow leopard?

By the way: I can't so simply upgrade to snow leopard because it's a hackintosh, so I prefer a different way..

Comment: See, this is why I answer all "can I develop iPhone apps on a PC?" questions with "buy a Mac mini or something".

Comment: Look I'm not that into programming to ipod yet, I'm pretty busy most of the time, it was either this or not programming at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Leopard but Apple have removed the download link. See the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582169/iphone-3-1-3-sdk-for-leopard) answer for the link.

Comment: Someone just sent me this exact link, it helped alot^^
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get version 3.1.4 (for Leopard) of xCode from http://connect.apple.com. Login and select 'developer tools' from the menu. And then search for 'Xcode 3.1.4 Developer Tools'. I'm using Xcode 3.1.4 with iPhone OS 3.1.3 with this setup.

Comment: Found it(: I only saw the dl for SDK and XCode bundle when I downloaded, I didn't assume there is another one for XCode alone (thought the bundle should've worked too..)

Thanks(;

Comment: After installing it seems like it deleted my previous sdk's,
I tried going to the SDKs library, and now I got only iPhoneOS3.0.sdk containing only the SDKSettings file, nothing more..
You got a clue?

Comment: The XCode version is obviusly used for MacOS developing, but do I must install an updated iphone sdk to develop for 3.1.3?
You said you work with leopard and iPhone OS 3.1.3, how come?

Comment: I've that version of xCode installed on Leopard and I can set my projects BaseSDK back as far as 2.2.1. Under "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs" I have iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk through to iphoneOS3.1.3sdk