# (MonoTouch): The Apple iPhone SDK is not installed

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I would like to build Iphone applications using C# / .net

When I build my simple application in MonoDevelop application for Monotouch, I get the following error:

**The Apple iPhone SDK is not installed.**

By mistake I may have installed software out of order for MonoTouch. Is there any way to fix my installation?

Here are my system details:

Mac OS X version : 10.5.8

Processor: 2.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

Downloaded and installed:

XCode 3.1.3
Mono 2.6.7 (Intel)
MonoDevelop 2.4.2
MonoTouch (eval 3-1.2.6)

If my out of order installs has messed up my IDE and not being able to build the solution, is there any way I could fix the install?

I went back and installed the above mentioned software in the correct order and I am still getting the following error message upon doing the build in MonoDevelop

**The Apple iPhone SDK is not installed.**

Please help me!!!!

Comment: Have you tried the newer version of XCode?  They recently came out with 4.0.x, and it's possible your version of MonoDevelop doesn't work with older versions of XCode.

Answer (score 1):

MonoTouch (like the iOS SDK) requires OSX 10.6.  Install the following in order:

1. OSX 10.6
2. Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS 4.3 SDK
3. MonoTouch 3.2.6

Answer (score 1):

You need to install MonoDevelop after Xcode.

First, upgrade to the latest iOS using the apple software update tool. Then, download Xcode.

Go to Finder > Applications > MonoDevelop. Right click it and select trash. Go back to the installer and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The Monotouch [installation documentation](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation) claims that 10.5 is supported.
Assuming that this is still the case, you will need to install an older iOS SDK that supports 10.5, ie 3.1.3.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582169/iphone-3-1-3-sdk-for-leopard) for details on where to find the older iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to be up and running after I bought snow leapord (10.6.3) , upgraded to 10.6.6, and installed every thing in the right order.

Now I am developing happily with MonoTouch.