# monotouch development on 10.5.8

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I can not (or do not know how to) upgrade my mac to 10.6.6

Currently I am running Mac Os X 10.5.8

What downloads do I need to be able to install MonoTouch for 10.5.8? Is it even possible?

According to Professional Iphone programming with Monotouch book,

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-iPhone-Programming-MonoTouch-Programmer/dp/047063782X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1301271660&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047063782X)

page I only need 10.5.7 version.

Is the book out dated?

Is there a way I can download older version of MonoTouch and be able to use it?

Please help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My apologies, the MonoTouch documentation is out of date.  Apple has refused to accept apps thru iTunes Connect with old versions, and they have dictated a 10.6 requirement, and as such we have dropped 10.5 support.  I have updated the outdated page.

Comment: Geoff, after upgrading to 10.6.6, following installation instructions closely, I am happily developing monotouch applications for iphone.

Answer (score 0):

The Monotouch [installation documentation](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation) claims that 10.5 is supported.
What is going wrong for you, and what leads you to believe that you need 10.6 instead?

Comment: I posted this question earlier detailing my issue. Please help. Thanks.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452120/monotouch-the-apple-iphone-sdk-is-not-installed

Comment: Ah, in that case I think you will need to either install an old version of the iOS SDK that supports 10.5, or upgrade to 10.6 and use the current iOS SDK.

Comment: You can find the iOS 3.1.3 SDK here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582169/iphone-3-1-3-sdk-for-leopard

Comment: Coxy, do you know the monodevelop version compatible with iOS3.1.3 ?

Comment: Check out the release notes for monotouch - eg. http://monotouch.net/Releases/MonoTouch_1/MonoTouch_1.9.5 Looks like you might need 1.9.5?